# I don't have a mod rewrite or htaccess file but "No input still shows up"

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've been at this for about four hours now, and google is basically useless. I have a fresh new install of IIS on my localhost machine here for testing. I am trying to get a PHP Codeigniter application to run on it, but no matter what I do it will only run the index page set with `$config['default_controller']`

If I try doing something like

`localhost/api/index.php/test/`

I will get the `no input file specified error`. From what I can tell is that this only occurs when you use `mod_rewrite` or a `web.config` file. I'm not using any of that stuff. So I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: So localhost/api serves the default controller?

Comment: IIS? What is this, the stone age? No, but seriously, it'll be hard for anyone to help you unless you post more info. To make things more obvious, you should revise your question so that it shows your complete config/config.php.

Comment: @BrianGottier agreed! I've just setup an IIS server and configured a CI install under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iistest with localhost pointing at C:\inetpub\wwwroot. It appears that the default web.config under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ is required for this to even work. So is there one present?

Comment: @MarkHill A default IIS install will create a web.config under your localhost folder. I can't get it to replicate your fault unless I go messing with things...